# How to create a responsive layout with a background image splitted in 3 different parts using HTML5/CSS/JS?

Tags: css, html, layout, background, responsiveness

That's for the layout masters.

How to create a responsive layout with a background image splitted in 3 different parts using HTML5/CSS/JS ?

I have 3 different images and I want to join them to create a dynamic background as a parchment style (please, see the reference image attached).  So I will have a fixed header, a dynamic middle part that I can write my HTML texts of any size and a fixed trailer image.

Does not matter if the solution will use backgrounds, divs, iframes, etc.  Any suggestions that could solve this puzzle are welcome!

[image]

Cheers,

David

Answer (score 1):

One method:

You can have 3 divs that have width with 100%

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="dynamic-body"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Here is a fiddle with just HTML and CSS, cropped img not that perfect.

http://jsfiddle.net/jbx5k4su/

Will update fiddle in a way to take out the html img tag and change the style of just the div.

Comment: Tks bro, but the problem of this solution is the HTML content breaking the middle background image. The expected result is the text written on the parchment image and also the 3 images backgrounds fitted perfectly.

Comment: hmm I was hoping to solve that by implementing the background to the div itself and not an img tag to accommodate the HTML elements being inserted within the div. How about the body tag having the parchment img for its background then have one div with margin top and bottom and put elements within this?

Comment: Sounds a great idea but I am afraid it will be almost impossible to join the images in a perfect fit.

Comment: What if you have a fixed header and footer (maybe with a z-index of 2) and just have your content be added in the middle div with the same background and just change dynamically?